# dynamically Controlling a Knob With Another one jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, return-value, jquery-knob

I have two knobs, I would like to control dynamically the value of the first one when moving the second one.

so far I have: 
(First Knob)

```
$('#inf-knob').knobRot({

                    classes: ['inf-knob'],
                    frameWidth: 250,
                    frameHeight: 250,
                    frameCount: 100,
                    detent: false,                  
                    discreteSteps: false,
                    stepCount: 0,
                    minimumValue: 0,
                    maximumValue: 2,
                    dragMultiplier: 0.01,
                    hideInput: true,
});

$('#inf-knob').on('knobdrag', function(e){
    //called until mouse button released

                    var dial = (500 * $('#inf-knob').val()).toFixed(1);

                    document.getElementById('freqmain').value = dial + " Hz";    
                    document.getElementById('freqmain2').value = dial;                   

});
```

(Second Knob Should Change the first one dynamically when moved)

```
$('#black-knob').on('knobdrag', function(e){

                  gainNode.gain.value = this.value;
                  console.log(this.value * 2);

                  $('#inf-knob').val(this.value * 2);

});
```

I have also tried using:

```
document.getElementById('inf-knob').value = this.value;
```

with no results.

What am I Missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As the Document of [KnobRot](http://www.domitable.com/static/side-projects/jquery-plugins/knobRot/demo.html) states , you should use :

To return the value of the specified knob:

```
$('myselector').knobRot('get')
```

To set the value of the specified knob, or knobs (will work with a collection):

```
$('myselector').knobRot('set', value)
```

And then you need to trigger `KnobRot` refresh. So in your case you can use it as :

```
 $('#black-knob').knobRot({           
    }).on('knobdrag', function(e){
        console.log(this.value * 2);
        $('#inf-knob').knobRot('set', this.value);
        $('#inf-knob').trigger('knobrefresh');
    });
```

### And , here is the [Working JsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SJNQa/2/)

P.S

1. The Fiddle demo doesn't show the graphical icon of Knob as i
   couldn't figure out all the inclusion required by KnobRot. But , you
   can drag hover below the text-field and drag when a expand cursor
   shows up.
2. I have never used such type of plugin.And the plugin documentation
   seems to be poor and not frequently updated. Why not use a different
   plugin fore-say **jQuery-Knob** [demo](http://anthonyterrien.com/knob/)
   and [code base](https://github.com/aterrien/jQuery-Knob).